# Using getComponent within a view in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've used the following in the past:

Ext.getCmp("MyLabel") to get access to an item in a view.

However, I've decided to use the 'itemId' property to name my components as I'm using multiple views with the same basic label inside.

I'd like to be able to create a class which provides a helper method which sets the text of the label.

Since the label will be one of the items inside the items property, I want to access it via the container or view instead of using the Ext.ComponentQuery static class. I don't need to search the DOM for it as I know it will be an item within the view and so should be more performant.
I've tried using:

```
view.getComponent("lblUserName")
view.getComponent("#lblUserName")
```

where the itemId property of my label is set to above. However it is just returning 'undefined'.

Is there any way to access the label from my view within a function of my view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
view.down("#lblUserName")
```

I see you say the `lbl` is a direct decendent - that's why `getComponent` *should* work -

`down` will search the hierarchy until it makes a match...worth a  try.